# Selecting conditions only when both rows (not either) are met

Tags: mysql, sql

Parts of the table that I am looking into is as follow:

table: store_inventories

```
+---------+----------+-------+----------+
| stor_id | title_id | qty   | minStock |
+---------+----------+-------+----------+
| 8042    | TC7777   |   630 |      630 |
| 8042    | TH1217   |     0 |      630 |
| 9012    | AK1231   |  -100 |       13 |
| 9012    | AK4153   |     5 |        1 |
| 9012    | BU2075   |    39 |        7 |
| 7131    | AW1234   | 10277 |     2055 |
| 7131    | AW5678   | 13150 |     2630 |
| 7131    | BU1032   |   545 |      109 |
| 7131    | BU2075   |    35 |        7 |
```

How can I select title_id from this table with where conditions that will meet both (not either) stor_ids 9012 and 7131.

The result should be

```
+----------+
| title_id | 
+----------+
| BU2075   |
```

I tried inner join and using and statement but they either returning wrong result or empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE` clause to filter the stor_ids and `HAVING` to count the instances of the rows return in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  title_id
FROM    store_inventories
WHERE   stor_ids IN (9012, 7131) -- 
GROUP   BY title_id
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Use `DISTINCT` if there title can have multiple rows of the same store.

```
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT stor_ids) = 2
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b368e/3).

Comment: @anonyXmous it is needed since the user specifically mentioned it in his post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a Join of subqueries:

```
SELECT  a.title_id
FROM    (select title_id 
    from store_inventories
    where stor_id=9012) a
JOIN  (select title_id 
    from store_inventories
    where stor_id=7131) b
ON (a.title_id=b.title_id)
```